# log single postgresql transaction for benchmarking

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to log any one execution of sql transaction script as desired? I don't want to have logging turned on all the time as I only need information from the transaction to generate a profiler report via http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/ ?!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. before this transaction do:

```
set log_min_duration_statement=0;
```

do your things, and then reset it back to original value.

But. There is no point in profiling single transaction, unless it's several thousand commands long. Otherwise - you can just read the logs. But remember - timing based on single executed transactions are practically worthless.

Comment: I am profiling a sql script to find out how much time is taken for each statement :)